# How do I put a line through the text after the check box is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, styles

This is what I got so far, I am positive the problem lies with this.checkBox

```
    var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
    checkBox.type = 'checkbox';
    if (this.checkBox) {
        inputItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    } else {inputItem.style.textDecoration = "none";}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do something like this. When the checkbox changes, check and see if the checkbox is checked by looking at the `checked` property. If that's true, set the text decoration of the label to `line-through` otherwise you can set it to none.

```
checkBox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  labelText.style.textDecoration = checkBox.checked ? 'line-through' : 'none';
});
```

Here is a full example:

```js
var inputItem = document.getElementById("inputItem");
inputItem.focus();

// adds input Item to list
function addItem(list, input) {
  var inputItem = this.inputItem;
  var list = document.getElementById(list);
  var listItem = document.createElement("li");
  
  // Configure the delete button
  var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  deleteButton.innerText = "X";
  deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("Delete code!");
  });
  
  // Configure the label
  var label = document.createElement("label");
  var labelText = document.createElement("span");
  labelText.innerText = input.value;
  
  // Configure the check box
  var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
  checkBox.type = 'checkbox';
  
  checkBox.addEventListener('change', function() {
    labelText.style.textDecoration = checkBox.checked ? 'line-through' : 'none';
  });
  
  // Put the checkbox and label text in to the label element
  label.appendChild(checkBox);
  label.appendChild(labelText);
  
  // Put the label (with the checkbox inside) and the delete
  // button into the list item.
  listItem.appendChild(label);
  listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);
  
  list.appendChild(listItem);
  inputItem.focus();
  inputItem.select();
  return false;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>To-Do List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>To-Do List</h1>
  <form onsubmit="return addItem('list', this.inputItem)">
    <input type="text" id="inputItem" onfocus="this.value=''" onselect="this.value=''" placeholder="Enter a Task">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
  <ul id="list">
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried using if,else statement . I basically used the if, else statement in the question but replaced the statement with checkBox.checked. Any ideas why that doesn't work

Comment: You need an event handler. There is nothing to call that code. Your code runs once, but there is nothing calling it again. If you add an event handler that watches for a change and then updates the field it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this. Simply create an onclick handler and check for the element's `checked` property. Set your style accordingly.

```js
function toggleLineThrough(element) {
  if (element.checked) {
    document.getElementById("text").style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("text").style.textDecoration = "none";
  }
  
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleLineThrough(this)"/>
<p id="text">some random text</p>
```